# Extract days and times from string, convert to minutes and assign to variables in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**Background**
I have a string that can contain up to five different times, separated by spaces. The string is an export of a field in a back end database to a data warehouse (SQL Server 2008 R2).

```
 Back end database          ->  Data warehouse string
 [LF] = line feed code
+========+================+
|Company |SLA_Times       |
+========+================+
|ABC01   |                | ->  NULL
+--------+----------------+
|DEF01   |00:30:00[LF]    |
|        |[LF]            | ->  '00:30:00  1 08:00:00'
|        |1 08:00:00      |
+--------+----------------+
|GHI01   |00:15:00[LF]    |
|        |01:00:00[LF]    |
|        |01:00:00[LF]    | ->  '00:15:00 01:00:00 01:00:00 04:00:00 08:00:00'
|        |04:00:00[LF]    |
|        |08:00:00        |
+--------+----------------+
|JKL01   |08:00:00[LF]    |
|        |21:00:00[LF]    |
|        |4 09:00:00[LF]  | ->  '08:00:00 21:00:00 4 09:00:00 10 00:00:00 100 00:00:00'
|        |10 00:00:00[LF] |
|        |100 00:00:00    |
+--------+----------------+
|MNO01   |[LF]            |
|        |[LF]            | ->  '   16:00:00'
|        |[LF]            |
|        |16:00:00        |
+--------+----------------+
```

I was not allowed to post an image, so I had to construct the code above. I was going to include the following picture, so maybe it helps to see things clearer:

[image: DB to string]

The SLA_TIMES field contains up to five time indicators, separated by line feeds. The order of the times in the field correspond to five priorities (1-5) for which SLA times can be set. This order is reflected in the string of course. As you see, the line feeds in de SLA_TIMES field get converted to spaces.

Every time indicator can appear in two ways:

- either with only a time part, or
- with a natural day part and a time part, separated by a space.

Like this:

```
'00:30:00'   indicates 30 minutes
'4 09:00:00' indicates 4 natural days (4 x 24 hours) plus 9 hours (total 105 hours)
```

The maximum number of natural days I've seen in the database is 9999, but who knows what they enter in the future. ;-)

**The goal**
I need to:

- extract the time indicators from a string, say '00:30:00 02:00:00   2 16:00:00'
- convert them to minutes and
- place them in five variables, named @SLA_1 to @SLA_5.

In case a time is not set in the string (or there is no string and the field is NULL) it will be set to 0 in the variable. (In that case a default SLA time will be used.)

For example, for company ABC01 in the image above the values would be:

```
@SLA_1 = 0
@SLA_2 = 0
@SLA_3 = 0
@SLA_4 = 0
@SLA_5 = 0
```

For company DEF01 the values would be:

```
@SLA_1 = 30
@SLA_2 = 0
@SLA_3 = 1920
@SLA_4 = 0
@SLA_5 = 0
```

For company GHI01 the values would be:

```
@SLA_1 = 15
@SLA_2 = 60
@SLA_3 = 60
@SLA_4 = 240
@SLA_5 = 480
```

For company JKL01 the values would be:

```
@SLA_1 = 480
@SLA_2 = 1260
@SLA_3 = 6300
@SLA_4 = 14400
@SLA_5 = 144000
```

For company MNO01 the values would be:

```
@SLA_1 = 0
@SLA_2 = 0
@SLA_3 = 0
@SLA_4 = 960
@SLA_5 = 0
```

The variables will be used to compare the SLA times to the turnaround times of tickets.

Some examples strings are:

```
'00:30:00  1 08:00:00'
'00:15:00 01:00:00 01:00:00 04:00:00 08:00:00'
'08:00:00 21:00:00 4 09:00:00 10 00:00:00 100 00:00:00'
'   16:00:00'
'00:30:00 02:00:00   2 16:00:00'
'1 00:00:00 2 00:00:00 4 00:00:00 16 00:00:00 32 00:00:00'
' 02:00:00   9999 08:00:00'
```

**Steps taken so far**
Now I'm not so proficient in SQL and I've been scratching my head for almost a week now on how to accomplish this. I tried to come up with something using CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING, but couldn't wrap my brain around it. I know how to convert times into minutes

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(minute,'00:00:00','03:00:00')
```

but that hasn't brought me very far.

ANY help will be very much appreciated!!

Comment: Okay, well. I would start by normalizing this bad boy.

Comment: Well, that's not really an option, but I know what you mean. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this **partially solution** which creates a recorset with following columns: `Index`, `NaturalDays` and `Time`:

```
DECLARE @Txt NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @Txt = 
    N'00:15:00' + CHAR(10) + 
    '01:00:00' + CHAR(10) + 
    '01:00:00' + CHAR(10) + 
    '04:00:00' + CHAR(10) + 
    '123 08:00:00';

DECLARE @IndexSeparator1 INT, 
    @IndexSeparator2 INT,
    @IndexSeparator3 INT,
    @IndexSeparator4 INT;

SET @IndexSeparator1 = NULLIF( CHARINDEX(CHAR(10) ,@Txt), 0); 
SET @IndexSeparator2 = NULLIF( CHARINDEX(CHAR(10) ,@Txt, @IndexSeparator1+1), 0); 
SET @IndexSeparator3 = NULLIF( CHARINDEX(CHAR(10) ,@Txt, @IndexSeparator2+1), 0); 
SET @IndexSeparator4 = NULLIF( CHARINDEX(CHAR(10) ,@Txt, @IndexSeparator3+1), 0); 

SET @IndexSeparator1 = CASE WHEN @IndexSeparator1 IS NULL AND @IndexSeparator2 IS NULL THEN 4001 ELSE @IndexSeparator1 END
SET @IndexSeparator2 = CASE WHEN @IndexSeparator1 <> 4001 AND @IndexSeparator2 IS NULL AND @IndexSeparator3 IS NULL THEN 4000 ELSE @IndexSeparator2 END
SET @IndexSeparator3 = CASE WHEN @IndexSeparator2 <> 4001 AND @IndexSeparator3 IS NULL AND @IndexSeparator4 IS NULL THEN 4000 ELSE @IndexSeparator3 END

SELECT  
    z.Idx,
    CONVERT(INT, CASE WHEN z.TimeSeparator > 0 THEN LEFT(z.Value, z.TimeSeparator-1) END) AS NaturalDays,
    CONVERT(TIME(0), -- or DATETIME
    NULLIF(CASE 
        WHEN z.TimeSeparator > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(z.Value, z.TimeSeparator + 1, 4000)  
        WHEN z.TimeSeparator = 0 THEN z.Value
        ELSE ''
    END, '')) AS [Time]
FROM
(
    SELECT  *, PATINDEX('%[ ][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]', y.Value) AS TimeSeparator
    FROM
    (
        SELECT  x.Idx, LTRIM(RTRIM(x.Value)) AS Value
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 1 AS Idx, SUBSTRING(@Txt, 1, @IndexSeparator1 - 1) AS Value UNION ALL
            SELECT 2, SUBSTRING(@Txt, @IndexSeparator1 + 1, @IndexSeparator2 - @IndexSeparator1 - 1) UNION ALL
            SELECT 3, SUBSTRING(@Txt, @IndexSeparator2 + 1, @IndexSeparator3 - @IndexSeparator2 - 1) UNION ALL
            SELECT 4, SUBSTRING(@Txt, @IndexSeparator3 + 1, @IndexSeparator4 - @IndexSeparator3 - 1) UNION ALL
            SELECT 5, SUBSTRING(@Txt, @IndexSeparator4 + 1, 4000)
        ) x
    ) y
) z
```

Results:

```
Idx         NaturalDays Time
----------- ----------- --------
1           NULL        00:15:00
2           NULL        01:00:00
3           NULL        01:00:00
4           NULL        04:00:00
5           123         08:00:00
```

Note #1: Based on this example, you could create an inline function (ex. `dbo.MyFunction`).

Note #2: You could use this inline function thus:

```
SELECT @VarDays1 = f.NaturalDays, @VarTime1 = f.[Time] 
FROM dbo.MyFunction(@param) AS f 
WHERE f.Idx = 1 -- for @SLA_1
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, but I think I made the problem not clear enough. I would like to start with a string I have, for example

'08:00:00 21:00:00 4 09:00:00 10 00:00:00 100 00:00:00'

and split those time indicators up, turn them into minutes and assign those minutes to five variables.

Comment: [...] this **partially solution** [...]

Comment: Wasn't my intention to give a complete solution. This is just an partially and intermediary solution.